# JDBC Driver for Elasticsearch

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Is there any JDBC Driver for Elasticsearch, that would allow an application to send SQL Statements over the Indices?

I am looking for a solutions or partial solutions that makes ES look like an RDBMS.

I need to join data from one Index to the Other

Comment: You're probably looking for this plugin: https://github.com/NLPchina/elasticsearch-sql

Answer (score 0):

JDBC Driver doesn't exist for Elasticsearch. The problem is that Elasticsearch does not support ACID transactions and developer should  resolve this problem by yourself ([read more](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/concurrency-solutions.html)).
You can use restricted sql via plugin which mention @Val in comments. It supports JOIN and LEFT_JOIN but with some [restrictions](https://github.com/NLPchina/elasticsearch-sql/wiki/Join#limitations) too.

Answer (score 0):

CData Software (my employer) offers a JDBC Driver with cross-index JOIN capabilities. Where possible, the driver will translate a SQL query into a JSON request for the Elasticsearch JSON REST API.

If the query is not directly supported, the driver will request the relevant data and perform the JOIN in-memory on the client-side.

The driver is downloadable here: https://www.cdata.com/drivers/elasticsearch/jdbc/